# jsessionid setting in nginx server for session in yii?

Tags: php, session, yii, nginx, jsessionid

This is my setting in `default.conf`:

```
#
# The default server
#
#upstream tomcat_server {
# Tomcat is listening on default 8080 port
#       server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
#  }

server {
     listen       80;
     server_name xx.xx.xxx.xxx;
     root /var/www/html;   
     charset utf-8;
     set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

# autoindex off;
    # rewrite ^/$ /web/ permanent;
 location / {
    #root /var/www/html;
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
       # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/;

#rewrite .* /index.php last;  
try_files $uri $uri/ /web/index.php?$query_string;
}

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
    root /var/www/html/web;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

 location ~ \.php {
#proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/web/;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
     fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index  index.php;
     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include        fastcgi_params;
    }
## Images and static content is treated different
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
      access_log        off;
      expires           max;
     # root /var/www/html;
    }


}
```

This is my console :

[image]

My session Not working:

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('name',$name);
 Yii::app()->user->getState('name');
```

I need jsessionid for this.

What should I do for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to give `#777` permission to this folder:

```
 /var/lib/php/session
```

permission:

```
chmod -R 0777 /var/lib/php/session
```

For writing session data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename PHP's default session name add following lines after `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME...` in your nginx config file:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "session.name=JSESSIONID"
```

Comment: I am not asking this. I am asking about  JSESSIONID setting in nginx